# exception handling resources for java

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to understand throwing exceptions, in the method signature, or within the method itself as well as try/catch exception handlers.

My textbook is not very useful, and I'm not understanding under what situations do we throw exceptions or handle them? Can you provide me with a resource to better understand this, whether its a video or link.

Comment: Check out the official tutorial on exceptions, it is straightforward with good examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This youtube video demonstrates it pretty well.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_-3OLkXkzY)
It's easy once you have played around with it. Typical example is parsing input.